# Can't use AsyncTask to show ProgressDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to show a ProgressDialog while waiting for server's response.

My class JogarActivity does the following (My app is a quiz game):

1- Initialize variables

2- Verify if it is or not the first question (primeiraPergunta)

2.1- If it's the first question, calls UserFunctions.getJogar(). This function build an list with parameters and send it to a JSONParser class. JSONParser makes the http request and returns a JSONArray with data

2.2- If it isn't the first question, just retrieve the actual question from intent extras.

3- Try to parse JSONArray to string. If the user had already answered all questions in the actual category, this will return an Exception (JSONArray will be null), so it can show a dialog asking user to select another category.

4- Puts all data (question and answer options) on screen and wait for user's interaction.

5- When user select an answer, it calls UserFunctions.gerResposta(). This time, it will return a status message (correct, wrong, error, etc) after updating the database (ponctuation, answered questions etc). It will also retrieve the next question.

6- Show a dialog with info about the question and an OK button that, when pressed, restarts the activity. The next question is passed as intent.putExtra(), and primeiraPergunta (first question?) is setted to false.

*UserFunctions and JSONParser are not activities, so I can't use ProgressDialog inside them, as long as I can't retrieve application's context.
*JSONParser is used by other classes, so I prefer not to changing it
*I'm looking for another solution than rewriting everithing in JogarActivity (that will make necessary to change other classes too).

first below i've pasted JogarActivity without changes. Then, I've tried to add an AsyncTask to show the ProgressDialog, but it just doesn't appears on screen (AsyncTask.get() is used to make JogarActivity wait for results from asynctask). Finnaly, i've pasted another class (RegisterActivity) where the AsyncTask works just fine.

I guess AsyncTask is probably not the best approach, but I just want to make it works as soon as possible. This is not my code (except for RegisterActivity). After the app works i'll optimize it :)

==========JogarActivity.java====================

```
public class JogarActivity  extends Activity {

private static final String TAG_RESPOSTA = "resposta";
private static final String TAG_ID = "idt";
private static final String TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA = "primeiraPergunta";
private static final String TAG_JSON = "json";
private Integer idPergunta;
private String pergunta;
private String respostaRecebe; //Texto da resposta que o usuário escolheu
private String respostaConfere;
private String resposta;
private String idCategoria;
private String respostaCorreta;
private String[] arrayRespostas = new String[5];
private boolean primeiraPergunta;
private JSONArray json;
private JSONArray jsonResposta;
String idUser;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    setContentView(R.layout.jogar_layout);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String url = this.getString(R.string.urlSite);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> respostaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String idt = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
    primeiraPergunta = in.getBooleanExtra(TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA, true);

    TextView insertPergunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insertPergunta);
    ListView insertRespostas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listResposta);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_LOGIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer idUsuario = settings.getInt("idUsuario", 0);
    idUser = idUsuario.toString();


    if (primeiraPergunta){
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        json = userFunction.getJogar(idt, idUser);

    }else{
        try {
            json = new JSONArray(in.getStringExtra(TAG_JSON));
            json = json.getJSONArray(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    try{
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String s = json.toString(); // Se o usuário já respondeu todas as perguntas da categoria, retorna uma Exception
        try {
            idPergunta = json.getInt(0);
            pergunta = json.getString(1);
            for (int i=2; i<7 ; i++){
                resposta = json.getString(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_RESPOSTA, resposta);
                respostaList.add(map);
                arrayRespostas[i-2] = resposta;
            }

            respostaCorreta = json.getString(7);
            respostaConfere = arrayRespostas[Integer.parseInt(respostaCorreta)-1];
            idCategoria = json.getString(11);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        insertPergunta.setText(pergunta);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, respostaList,
                R.layout.resposta_data,
                new String[] { TAG_RESPOSTA }, new int[] {
                        R.id.insertResposta });

        insertRespostas.setAdapter(adapter);



        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = insertRespostas;


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                Integer pos = position + 1;
                String respostaEscolhida = pos.toString();
                String pergunta = idPergunta.toString();

                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                            final JSONArray jsonResposta = userFunction.getResposta(pergunta, idUser , respostaEscolhida, idCategoria);



                respostaRecebe = arrayRespostas[position];

                String mensagem = "";
                try {
                    mensagem = jsonResposta.getString(1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final String jrString = jsonResposta.toString();

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        JogarActivity.this).create();


                    if (respostaCorreta.equals(pos.toString())){
                        alertDialog.setTitle("PARABÉNS");   
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Resposta correta: "+respostaRecebe+"\n\n"+mensagem);
                    }
                    else{
                        alertDialog.setTitle("VOCÊ ERROU");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Sua resposta: "+respostaRecebe+"\n\nResposta correta: "+respostaConfere+"\n\n"+mensagem);

                    }
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JogarActivity.class);
                                //in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_ID, idCategoria);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA, false);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_JSON, jrString);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();

                        }


        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        AlertDialog sem_perguntas = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                JogarActivity.this).create();
            sem_perguntas.setTitle("PARABÉNS"); 
            sem_perguntas.setMessage("Você já respondeu todas as perguntas desta categoria!");

            sem_perguntas.setButton("VOLTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CategoriasJogarActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
            });

            sem_perguntas.show();
            //finish();
    }



   //finish(); 
}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_jogar, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_pularPergunta:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JogarActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(JogarActivity.this, "Pergunta Pulada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

==============JogarActivity with AsyncTask (ProgressDialog doesn't appears)=============

```
public class JogarActivity  extends Activity {

private static final String TAG_RESPOSTA = "resposta";
private static final String TAG_ID = "idt";
private static final String TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA = "primeiraPergunta";
private static final String TAG_JSON = "json";
private Integer idPergunta;
private String pergunta;
private String respostaRecebe; //Texto da resposta que o usuário escolheu
private String respostaConfere;
private String resposta;
private String idCategoria;
private String respostaCorreta;
private String[] arrayRespostas = new String[5];
private boolean primeiraPergunta;
private JSONArray json;
private JSONArray jsonResposta;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
Context ctx = this;
String idUser;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    setContentView(R.layout.jogar_layout);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String url = this.getString(R.string.urlSite);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> respostaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String idt = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
    primeiraPergunta = in.getBooleanExtra(TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA, true);

    TextView insertPergunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insertPergunta);
    ListView insertRespostas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listResposta);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_LOGIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer idUsuario = settings.getInt("idUsuario", 0);
    idUser = idUsuario.toString();


    if (primeiraPergunta){
        //UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        //json = userFunction.getJogar(idt, idUser);
        AsyncTask jogar = new Jogar().execute("url", "http://www.qranio.com/mobile/perguntas.php", "categoria", idt, "idUsuario", idUser);
        try {
            json = (JSONArray) jogar.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try {
            json = new JSONArray(in.getStringExtra(TAG_JSON));
            json = json.getJSONArray(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    try{
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String s = json.toString(); // Se o usuário já respondeu todas as perguntas da categoria, retorna uma Exception
        try {
            idPergunta = json.getInt(0);
            pergunta = json.getString(1);
            for (int i=2; i<7 ; i++){
                resposta = json.getString(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_RESPOSTA, resposta);
                respostaList.add(map);
                arrayRespostas[i-2] = resposta;
            }

            respostaCorreta = json.getString(7);
            respostaConfere = arrayRespostas[Integer.parseInt(respostaCorreta)-1];
            idCategoria = json.getString(11);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        insertPergunta.setText(pergunta);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, respostaList,
                R.layout.resposta_data,
                new String[] { TAG_RESPOSTA }, new int[] {
                        R.id.insertResposta });

        insertRespostas.setAdapter(adapter);



        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = insertRespostas;


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){




                Integer pos = position + 1;
                String respostaEscolhida = pos.toString();
                String pergunta = idPergunta.toString();



                //UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                //final JSONArray jsonResposta = userFunction.getResposta(pergunta, idUser , respostaEscolhida, idCategoria);
                AsyncTask jogar = new Jogar().execute("url", "http://www.qranio.com/mobile/resposta.php", "id_pergunta", pergunta, "id_usuario", idUser, "resposta", respostaEscolhida, "categoria", idCategoria);

                try {
                    jsonResposta = (JSONArray) jogar.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                respostaRecebe = arrayRespostas[position];

                String mensagem = "";
                try {
                    mensagem = jsonResposta.getString(1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final String jrString = jsonResposta.toString();

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        JogarActivity.this).create();


                    if (respostaCorreta.equals(pos.toString())){
                        alertDialog.setTitle("PARABÉNS");   
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Resposta correta: "+respostaRecebe+"\n\n"+mensagem);
                    }
                    else{
                        alertDialog.setTitle("VOCÊ ERROU");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Sua resposta: "+respostaRecebe+"\n\nResposta correta: "+respostaConfere+"\n\n"+mensagem);

                    }
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JogarActivity.class);
                                //in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_ID, idCategoria);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA, false);
                                i.putExtra(TAG_JSON, jrString);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();

                        }


        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        AlertDialog sem_perguntas = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                JogarActivity.this).create();
            sem_perguntas.setTitle("PARABÉNS"); 
            sem_perguntas.setMessage("Você já respondeu todas as perguntas desta categoria!");

            sem_perguntas.setButton("VOLTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CategoriasJogarActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
            });

            sem_perguntas.show();
            //finish();
    }



   //finish(); 
}

/*public void colocaResposta (int i, JSONArray json, ArrayList respostaList) throws JSONException{
    resposta = json.getString(i);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TAG_RESPOSTA, resposta);
    respostaList.add(map);
}*/





public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_jogar, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_pularPergunta:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JogarActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(JogarActivity.this, "Pergunta Pulada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


class Jogar extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... values) {
        String url = values[1];
        int count = values.length;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        for (int i=2; i<count; i++){
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(values[i], values[i+1]));
            i++;
        }

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url, params);

        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

=================RegisterActivity (Works fine)======================

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity{
EditText reg_fullname;
EditText reg_email;
EditText reg_login;
EditText reg_password;
EditText reg_password2;
Spinner reg_country;
Spinner reg_genre;
EditText reg_birthday;
EditText reg_promocode;
Button btnRegister;
Context ctx = this;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONArray json;
String status;
String msg;

String fullname;
String email;
String login;
String password;
String password2;
String country;
String genre;
String birthday;
String promocode;

boolean finishActivity = false;

/**
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // Closing registration screen
            // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
            finish();
        }
    });

    reg_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
    reg_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    reg_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_login);
    reg_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    reg_password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password2); //confirmação de senha
    reg_country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.reg_country);
    reg_genre = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.reg_genre);
    reg_birthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_birthday);
    reg_promocode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_promocode);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);


    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fullname = reg_fullname.getText().toString();
            email = reg_email.getText().toString();
            login = reg_login.getText().toString();
            password = reg_password.getText().toString();
            password2 = reg_password2.getText().toString();
            country = reg_country.getSelectedItem().toString();
            genre = reg_genre.getSelectedItem().toString();
            birthday = reg_birthday.getText().toString();
            promocode = reg_promocode.getText().toString();

            boolean validation = true;
            String message = "Campo de preencimento obrigatório";

            if(fullname.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_fullname.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            if(email.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_email.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            if(!email.matches(".*@.*")){
                reg_email.setError("O endereço de email não é válido");
                validation = false;
            }
            if(login.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_login.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_password.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            if(password2.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_password2.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            if(!password.equals(password2)){
                reg_password2.setError("A confirmação de senha não confere");
                validation = false;
            }
            if(birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                reg_birthday.setError(message);
                validation = false;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat bd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            if(bd.parse(birthday, new ParsePosition(0)) == null){
                reg_birthday.setError("Esta data não é válida! Preencha novamente, usando o formato dd/mm/aaaa");
                validation = false;
            }

            if(validation){
            new Register().execute();
            }

        }
    });



}


class Register extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    pDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    json = userFunction.newUser(fullname, email, login, password, country, genre, birthday, promocode);

    return json;

}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            RegisterActivity.this).create();

            try {
                status = json.getString(0);
                msg = json.getString(1);
                Log.d("Status", status);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("RegisterActiviry", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                status = null;
            }

            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("erro")){
                alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
                alertDialog.setMessage(msg);

            }else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("sucesso")){
                alertDialog.setTitle("Sucesso!");
                alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
                finishActivity = true;
            }else{
                alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");   
                alertDialog.setMessage("Não foi possível realizar seu cadastro, tente novamente mais tarde.");
            }


            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(finishActivity){
                    finish();
                    }else{
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

}
```

}

}

Answer (score 2):

put you dialog like below I hope it will work.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                   //Your dailog 

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I've used it before calling UserFunction, but the dialog still doesn't appears. Edit: If i don't use pDialog.dismiss(), it appears (but don't disappear after servers response).

Comment: pDialog.dismiss() don't call in post execute , fist analyse where and whe you need to dismiss the dialog. put "pDialog.dismiss()" in above Thread...please check before closing it opened or not you hve boolean method to know dialog opened or not.